# Angular/TypeScript: Get background Image URL of <p>

Tags: angular, typescript

How would I get the `background-image` of `<p>` element in angular/typescript, i.e I have below element I only want to get image value `image.jpeg`, how would I get that?

```
<p
  class="employer__image"
  style='background-image: url("image.jpeg")'>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access it using `style.backgroundImage`, it will return 'url("image.jpeg")'

Comment: i mean, what returns `console.log(employerImage)` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170994/discussion-between-kamran-khatti-and-fabio-carpinato).